# Website that uses iPhoto or Photos library as the database

Tags: photos, websites, photos.app, web-sharing

I've begun creating a centralised iPhoto library of all the family photos and was hoping to share it with my family members in a well presented way rather than just sending them the raw images.

My current process is:
- Scan the image
- Add a rough date to the meta of the image in iPhoto
- Use facial recognition in iPhoto to group / tag images by who they are

The last two steps are fairly pointless if I am just providing raw files. Ideally I would like to create a website, that allows me to display the images from the iPhoto library in the following ways:

- by album

- by recently added

- by facially recognised people

- by date

I can't find anyone who has done this before and I can't find anyone who is pulling content straight from iPhoto onto a website. Any ideas of how I could do this, has anyone done this before, does anyone have any alternatives that would enable me to still achieve display options in the above 4 ways?

Worth noting that I have considered just uploading them all to Facebook and making the album private but their privacy policy doesn't excite me when the images in this photo repository include photos of myself naked as a child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using iCloud Photo Sharing?

This can be used to share specific photo albums, so you could create one for each of the four categories. You can also share these as a *public website* so that people who aren't part of Apple's ecosystem can also view them.

For more information refer to: [iCloud Photo Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202786).

**NOTE:** One limitation you should be aware of is that currently iCloud Photo Sharing limits you to sharing no more than 5,000 photos/videos.

Comment: I had considered it but didn't know that they could be shared as a public website and I thought that the albums used your iCloud's limited 5GB storage. Reading the attached article it sounds like it doesn't would that be a valid assumption?

Comment: Correct! :) Although all photos in your shared albums are actually uploaded to and stored in iCloud, they don't count towards your iCloud storage space. Just remember though, that you still do have a limit of 5000 photos for iCloud Photo Sharing.

Answer (score -2):

You can transfer your photos to PC, and save them there, then use some kind of USB to copy those photos to anyone you need to share with.